# Deletion of data from table

Tags: postgresql

I want to prepare a batch file/SQL Job which runs on every month 1st to delete the data from the table in PostgreSQL (which is in server) older than 2-months.
Eg: Let us consider that today is Mar1st. So today the batch file should run, deleting all the data upto January 31st(should not delete Feb).

Take server name as "Test" or "Development"

So if I give "Development" it should delete the data in "Development" environment else if "Test" is given then in "Test Environment"

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is exactly your question or where are you struggling in your use case?

Comment: You already know what you want to do so that's a good start already. That said before getting help from here you'll need to show us your attempt at helping yourself (i.e. some code) cause no-one here is going to write the full solution for you. At least not for free.

Answer (score 0):

You may use table partitioning https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html

To create automatic background job you can use pg_partman psql extension https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman.